# Сохранение позиции пагинации

Tags: bootstrap, backbone.js, pagination

У меня есть пагинация к таблице сделанная на `Bootstrap` и `Backbone`. Допустим я на 5-й странице пагинации, после нажатия на строку таблицы открывается новая страница через роутер. После перехода обратно к таблице с пагинацией она сбрасывает меня на первую страницу, а не на 5-ю когда я перешел был на новое окно. Как сделать так, чтоб при возврате назад (нажатие на кнопку Назад, к которой поставлен ивент перехода к таблице) моя пагинация сохраняла вид тот, который был до перехода на новую страницу? Через хеш не могу использовать пагинацию так как потом вылазят косяки с `window.history.back()`. Возможно, есть другие пути решения проблемы?

Comment: Скажите, почему через хеш не вариант? Имеется ввиду хеш урла?

Answer (score 1):

Я использую пагинацию в url. К примеру

```
#!/user/list/page=2/limit=20
```

Дальше у меня создан компонент навигации, в который я передаю значения, в данном случае, что-то типа

```
var pagin = new PaginView({page: 2, limit: 20});
```

и делаю вставку в нужный регион

```
this.regions.content.show(pagin);
```

Т.е как бы не происходила навигация, всегда корректно происходит отображение.

Общий смысл - просто перерендерить вьюшку при изменении данных.

PS только увидел, что было указано, что хеш не вариант.